# Retrieving data from api that's not in json or hash format

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an api call that produces results in this format:

```
Number|Station name|Latitude|Longitud|Distance (km)
455044|Station 1   |-60.2257|249.4452|0.0
153045|Station 2   |-60.3000|249.5000|9.2
```

I'm not too sure what this format is called though. Text format? XML?

```
@list = HTTParty.get("www.apiurl.com")
```

I'm using HTTParty to call the api and parse the data. But how do I get the results in a hash or array using the first line as a key? So for example:

```
@list.each do |item|
  item['Number']
end
```

Would return all of the numbers.

Comment: Its basically just CSV but with pipes as delimeters. AKA garbage data.  https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Comment: Thanks @max i thought it looked familiar. It is a weird way of outputting data.